# Scid not registering multiple sub-variations

Tags: software, scid

I am trying to save multiple lines in the same game, like the following:

1.e4 1..e5 (1..c5 2. Nf3 (2.Nc3)) 2.Nf3

However, when I try to do this, it is only allowing me to keep either 2.Nf3 or 2.Nc3 after the c5 line. I do remember being able to save multiple lines earlier on another laptop of mine.

Note that I am able to save multiple lines where the first move of the variations are different, like:

1.e4 1..e5 (1..c5) (1..c6) (1..e6)

My About Scid section:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Finally found the solution to this on [ScidWiki](https://sourceforge.net/p/scid/wiki/HowToAnnotateGames/)

---

***To explicitly add a new variation starting with the same move (e.g. to simplify deeply nested variation trees) press Ctrl-A to explicitly add a variation and only then play the move.***